# Find position of a number in array closest to given number

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am searching for an elegant way to find the closest element in an array to a given value.

Here is a working implementation:

```cpp
std::vector<double> array = { /* numbers */ };
double num = /* given number */;
double min_diff = std::abs(array[0] - num);
size_t best_pos = 0;
for (size_t i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
    double curr_diff = std::abs(array[i] - num);
    if (curr_diff < min_diff) {
        min_diff = curr_diff;
        best_pos = i;
    }
}
std::cout << best_pos << std::endl;
```

Is there a better solution (not algorithmically, but more beautiful)? Maybe with `<algorithm>`?

There is no restriction on `best_pos` type, it can be `std::iterator`.

Comment: `std::upper_bound` or `std::lower_bound` would be a good start if it is sorted

Comment: A range based `for` loop may be?

Comment: @NathanOliver it is not sorted unfortunately

Comment: `std::min` with custom predicate. beauty is very subjective. Why do you think your current solution is not elegant? "produces correct results" is imho rather beautiful ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how can I get a position in array with range based for?

Comment: Counting the iterations.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it does not fit on the paper :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the element that minimizes some function you can use `std::min_element`. Note that this isn't the most efficient, as it evaluates the function to be minimized for every comparison. When the function to be minimized is more costly, you'd maybe rather populate a container of the functions results and then find the minimum in that. Though as long as it is merely a call to `std::abs` that should be fine:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){ 
    std::vector<double> vect = { 1,2,3,6,7,8 };
    double num = 4;
    auto it = std::min_element(vect.begin(),vect.end(),[num](double x,double y){ 
        return std::abs(num-x) < std::abs(num-y); 
    });
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```